# Do not highlight a Qt button on hover

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I want to make a `QPushButton` look exactly the same regardless of whether the mouse is currently hovering over it or not, or if that is not possible, make it so that the background color of the button does not change on hover. So far I have tried,

```
QPushButton::hover { background-color: palette(button); }
```

No other option for `palette()` seems to do what I want, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose - instead of making attempts to overwrite default stylesheet for `hover` - install an `eventFilter` to filter out all `QEvent::HoverEnter`. For example, add such a tiny class somewhere:

```
class ButtonEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
    {
        Q_UNUSED(obj)
        if (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

And then install this filter as:

```
ui->pushButton->installEventFilter(new ButtonEventFilter);
```

Then, there will be no `hover` event so your `QPushButton` will remain unchanged.

===================

If you are using **Python**:

```
class ButtonEventFilter(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.HoverEnter:
            return True
        return False
```

And then install filter:

```
filter = ButtonEventFilter(self)
self.ui.pushButton.installEventFilter(filter)
```

Example from docs:
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.eventFilter

Remember to have imported `QObject` and `QEvent`. If you are using PySide 2:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QEvent
```

Comment: Ah, so I'm actually using `PyQT`. You wouldn't know how to do this in Python, by any chance?

Comment: @sammosummo - I have added Python version, but for `PySide 2`. It should work in very similar manner however for `PyQt`, since we rely on the very basic methods of `QObject`.